# How to install Haskell on Mac

Tags: macos, haskell

I am trying to install Haskell on Mac, and doing it as instructed on Haskell site [Haskell site](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/). 
When I run the script from above website on terminal, it says to install "ghcup", "ghc" and "cabal". However, it seems that it installs "ghcup" successfully, but an error occurs when it comes to install "ghc".

> Error: ghc: unknown version :lion

how can I fix this?  or, is there another way to install Haskell on Mac?

(I saw similar posts but they are too old)

Comment: Are you still running macOS Lion? It's end-of-life and no longer receives critical security updates, yet you're obviously using it on the Internet. Upgrade to Catalina and try again.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hi, thanks for the advice, I am upgrading to Catalina, hope it works

Comment: If you can part with 25 dollars, there's also the [Haskell for Mac IDE](http://haskellformac.com/).

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica After updating to Catalina, the same way of installation is worked. Thanks! I could mark your solution as accepted if you put it as an answer.

Comment: @arslan Okay, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running macOS Lion, which is ancient, insecure, and no longer supported by Apple. As such, most modern software isn't tested for compatibility with it anymore, and a lot of it won't work. Upgrading to a modern version of macOS such as Catalina will make it work.

Comment: worked. However, it seems path variables needs to be set.

Answer (score -2):

There are different options to get a working Haskell development environment on your Mac. The most popular seem to be

- [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html)
- Install via [homebrew](https://brew.sh)
- The Haskell Tool [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/)

Of course, you can also install most tools individually by hand or compile everything from source.

Together with the type of installation, you need to choose how to build your projects: Using [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/) or [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).

My personal preferences as a beginner is Stack, because (a) the entire Haskell tool stack is installed locally for each project, so you don't get into problems with conflicting versions of certain tools; (b) dependencies are curated, such that you do not need to deal with incompatible versions of libraries. From a beginner's perspective, it is very helpful that I can focus on actual development work and less on infrastructure and tooling.

Comment: This answer looks like it's written based on only the question's title and not the body.

Comment: The question states "or, is there another way to install Haskell on Mac?"

Comment: But given the actual underlying problem, your other methods will almost certainly fail too.